# "As many people travelled by train as by car in the Netherlands in 1975"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of the following sentence?

> As many people travelled by train as by car in the Netherlands in 1975

I haven't encountered "**as many ... as**" used like this before and couldn't find an exemplary sentence in my grammar book (English Grammar in Use) I'm familiar with sentences like ''I read as many books as you read during the mid-term break.'' Also, English to Turkish translation services didn't give me a meaningful sentence.

Comment: "The number of people who travelled by train was equal to the number who travelled by car." There is no difference in usage.

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that there were as many train travellers as there were car travellers.

*As many X as Y* is an everyday idiom in English - and the sentence simply expands upon that.

"As many cars are red as are blue" is just another way of saying "There are as many red cars as blue cars".

Comment: Thank you. It was from an IELTS Academic writing task 1 question, but in the pie chart, the number of people who travelled by train isn't equal to the number of people who travelled by car. Also this statement is correct, depending on answers page. That confused me a lot. Is it correct to write ''as many X as Y'' even the amounts compared are not exactly equal?

Comment: If the amounts/totals are not equal, there are NOT as many of X as of Y. However, if you were comparing 100 million train travellers with 101 million car travellers, you could certainly use the phrase loosely. People would not expect it to be accurate down to the last unit.

Comment: See here https://www.englishforums.com/English/DescriptionChartAnyoneAssessThank-Advance/bnddgl/post.htm#:~:text=In%201975%2C%20the%20largest%20percentage,was%20cycling%2C%20with%2023%25.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm talking about this pie chart too, it's on page 95 in The Official Cambridge Guide to IELTS. However, there is no additional information but just two pie charts. The portions of car and train traffic don't look the same. I think it's controversial as there isn't any additional information, just two pie charts. Thank you so much for letting me know about ''englishforums.com''

Comment: @orhantorun - 'as many as' does not require equality of totals. If 10 people went by train, and 8 went by car, I can say as many people went by train as by car. In fact 2 more people went by train as well.